# Node's createHmac function

Tags: hmac, node.js

for the node.js crypto command:

```
crypto.createHmac('this is a test', key);
```

What is node expecting for `key`'s encoding?

utf8? a binary buffer?

Answer (score 1):

Since javascript uses UTF-16 strings, I suspect it is expecting a UTF-16 encoded string.  Just to clarify, your first parameter should be a hash algorithm ('sha1', 'md5', etc.) not the data to be encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

First parameter should be the algorythm, not the input to be HMACed, should be [one of the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168703/crypto-algorithm-list) -

```
MD5
SHA
SHA1
SHA256
SHA384
```

The [key](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) is a secret / salt string.

[crypto.createHmac](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhmac_algorithm_key) returns a stream, you write your input into it and once you start reading, it returns the computed digests.